# Poodle vulnerability need to change SSL 3.0 to TLS

Tags: apache, ssl, poodle-attack, transport-security

I have implemented SSL(https) in my website, but when I checked the certificate it is showing poodle vulnerability. So it suggests me that I needed to change `SSL 3.0` to `TLS`. I am  using `Apache2.4`. Please guide me how can I change `SSL 3.0`  to `TLS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache

To disable SSLv3 on your Apache server you can configure it using the following, both in the SSL configuration section and in all SSL-enabled virtual hosts explicitly:

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in the `VirtualHost`configuration section for your site:

`SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3`

It will disable SSLv2 & SSLv3, while keeping the others (TLS 1.0+) enabled.